# What 3d converter can handle .iges, .step, .sat, .dwg, .gdl?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, export, cross-platform

I'm looking for a 3d Converter which can handle the following file types:

**Import**

- iges
- step
- sat

**Export**

- dwg
- gdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few. Not sure if they cover all the formats, but .iges, .step and .dwg should be covered at least:

[3DWin](http://www.tb-software.com/products_2.html)

[Polytrans](http://www.okino.com/conv/conv.htm)

[3D Object Converter](http://3dconverter.webege.com/)